# How to print data from SQLite database in Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm having problems printing contents of SQLite database into a Flask web page.

The output of the code below does not return the records I have fetched from the database into the Flask web page which is expecting it, and will display into a table.

The code I have so far:

**flask.py**

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask import render_template 
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('sqlite_test.db') c = conn.cursor()
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') def index():    
 c.execute('SELECT * FROM facebook_posts')    
 return render_template('flask.html', rows = c.fetchall())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**flask.html**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>StatusID</th>
            <th>Status Message</th>
            <th>Link</th>
            <th>Status Type</th>
            <th>Status Link</th>
            <th>Status Published</th>
            <th>Reaction Count</th>
            <th>Comment Count</th>
            <th>Share Count</th>
            <th>Like Count</th>
            <th>Love Count</th>
            <th>Wow Count</th>
            <th>Haha Count</th>
            <th>Sad Count</th>
            <th>Angry Count</th>          
          </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    {% for row in rows %}
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{status_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{status_message}}</td>
                    <td>{{link_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{status_type}}</td>
                    <td>{{status_link}}</td>
                    <td>{{status_published}}</td>
                    <td>{{num_reactions}}</td>
                    <td>{{num_comments}}</td>
                    <td>{{num_shares}}</td>
                    <td>{{num_likes}}</td>
                    <td>{{num_loves}}</td>
                    <td>{{num_wows}}</td>
                    <td>{{num_hahas}}</td>
                    <td>{{num_sads}}</td>
                    <td>{{num_angrys}}</td>
                  </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </tbody>
              </table>
```

Am I missing something or might have overlooked?

Comment: Your filename is `flask.html` and you are using `index.html`.

Comment: @KlausD Hey, thanks! I did not notice that. Unfortunately, I have changed the filename already but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And at `index.html`, if status_id and status_message ... are you SQLite column, you should use `row.status_id` and `row.status_message` and so on.

Comment: Hey, thank you, your suggestion solved part of my problem. But it didn't work right away. I have to change some code in my **flask.py** file.

Comment: Oh, your `flask.py` may: `cur = c.execute('SELECT * FROM facebook_posts')  `  and then `rows = cur.fetchall()`. By the way, I think you should read [document](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlite3/) firstly.

Comment: It turns out that I have to put the data into a dictionary first iterate through it and use the fetchall() function then put the data inside a variable before passing it to the view. I now have solved it. Again, thank you very much!